# How to activate javafx to existing project in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, maven-2, javafx

I have maven project with javafx code. When I checkout this project to Netbeans, id cant find javafx packages even if I set "Default JavaFX" platform for this projeckt. But it finds javafx packages for new javafx project.

Answer (score 0):

you must set the build path and adding the external .jar - file from you javafx path.

You need to add this:

- jfxrt.jar

greetz

Comment: But as I know jdk 7 includes jfxrt.jar by default. So in, for example, IntelliJ I shouldn't this external jar.

Comment: IntelliJ is actually doing the wrong thing. For Java jdk7u11- jfxrt.jar is included with the Java runtime, but not on the Java boot class path - so IntelliJ shouldn't really be including it on the default Java runtime path for projects.  See: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8003170.  Anyway, by Java 7u12 jfxrt.jar should be on the classpath for all Java executions, so, when that is released, you will never need to place jfxrt.jar on the build and execution path.

Comment: Unfortunately, my previous comment didn't come true and the related bug was closed as won't fix for Java 7. The bug is fixed for Java 8, so, if you use that, then you don't need to place jfxrt.jar on the build and execution path.

Answer (score 0):

not really supported/implemented just yet on the netbeans javafx modules side.
See the relevant enhancements filed.

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221184

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222295

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot. So it is time to use ItelliJ IDEA!

Answer (score 0):

You must add some JARs to your project in order to build it.

Select "Properties" in your project and choose Libraries. There, select "Add JAR/Folder" and navigate to the JDK folder. There, inside jre/lib you find jfxrt.jar. Add it.

Now, javafx package is recognized.